# Output results from multiple select statements as rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, rows

I am wondering if there is a way to show the results from multiple select queries as rows.

If I have SELECT queries as below:

```
SELECT count(*), MAX(created_date) from TABLE1;

SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(created_date) from TABLE2;
```

The output I expect is

```
 +----------+-------------------+
 | Count(*) | MAX(created_date) |
 +----------+-------------------+
 |   234    |     10-may-14     |
 |   847    |     03-Apr-14     |
 +----------+-------------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`UNION [ALL]`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(created_date) from TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), MAX(created_date) from TABLE2;
```

If you wanted to identify the source of each row you can just create another column:

```
SELECT 'TABLE1' AS Source, COUNT(*), MAX(created_date) from TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TABLE2' AS Source, COUNT(*), MAX(created_date) from TABLE2;
```